# Snippet shortcut not showing in intellisense

Tags: visual-studio

I have several custom snippets that show up when I use "Insert Snippet", and they have also shortcuts assigned to them, but whenever I try to use the shortcut directly, they don't show up in Intellisense. If I type the full shortcut and press tab, the snippet is still inserted... But I'd really like the shortcuts to show in Intellisense.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm having the same issue.